# wmctrl compilation error - missing library

Tags: compiling, make, cross-compilation

wmctrl is a utility application that controls GNOME/linux windows from
command line

I am building a wmctrl binary from source, however I am having a problem compiling it, it complains about not finding lXmu

```
/usr/bin/ld : cannot find -lXmu
```

I do have under /usr/lib

```
libXmu.so.6
libXmu.so.6.2.0
libXmu.so
```

and under /usr/lib64

```
libXmu.so.6
libXmu.so.6.2.0
```

Comment: It is not a compiler, it is a linker problem. Where did you get source from? Are you sure it is ok? Did you changed something in makefile or configure?

Comment: I didn't change anything. What information do i need to fetch for to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

---

> /usr/bin/ld : cannot find -lXmu

`-lXmu` means libXmu.so , provided by the package libXmu-devel, 64bits.

Please install, like # `yum install libXmu-devel.x86_64`

---